# ViewController Containment with Subclassing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

in an attempt to up my "getting away from massive view controllers" I am trying some stuff with view controller containment.

Here's what I want:

- have a base class with a scroll view and an embedded stack view
- inherit from that class with an implementation of my desired scene
- being able to add child view controllers as needed to my implementation

I expect something like this:

[image]

Here's the code I am trying to achieve this with:

```
import UIKit

/**
Base class
*/
class PrototypeStackViewController: UIViewController {

    private let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let s = UIScrollView()
        s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        s.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return s
    }()

    private let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let s = UIStackView()
        s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        s.axis = .vertical
        s.alignment = .fill
        s.distribution = .fill
        s.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return s
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        let  nstraint = stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.frameLayoutGuide.heightAnchor)
        stackViewHeightConstraint.priority = .defaultLow

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),

            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leadingAnchor),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.trailingAnchor),
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor),
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor),

            stackViewHeightConstraint
        ])
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func add(child: UIViewController) {
        addChild(child)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    func remove(child: UIViewController) {
        guard child.parent != nil else { return }

        child.willMove(toParent: nil)
        stackView.removeArrangedSubview(child.view)
        child.view.removeFromSuperview()
        child.removeFromParent()
    }
}

/**
Implementation of my scene
*/
class PrototypeContainmentViewController: PrototypeStackViewController {

    lazy var topViewController: PrototypeSubViewController = {
        let t = PrototypeSubViewController()
        t.view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        t.label.text = "Top View Controller"
        return t
    }()

    lazy var centerViewController: PrototypeSubViewController = {
        let t = PrototypeSubViewController()
        t.view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        t.label.text = "Center View Controller"
        return t
    }()

    lazy var bottomViewController: PrototypeSubViewController = {
        let t = PrototypeSubViewController()
        t.view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        t.label.text = "Bottom View Controller"
        return t
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        add(child: topViewController)
        add(child: centerViewController)
        add(child: bottomViewController)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }
}

/**
Sample View Controller
*/
class PrototypeSubViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return l
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed

        view.addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        ])
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

If you look close, you can even see the "Bottom View Controller" label – but on top the green center view controller.

I am missing something here in my love-hate-relation with auto layout, that much is for sure...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the width constraint that ensures that the stack view fills the width of the scroll view:

```
stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)
```

Also I would set your label constraints in this way:

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 12),
    label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor, constant: -12),
    label.top.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
    label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
])
```

Comment: Definitely a push into the right direction, thanks. With the width anchor in place, it spans over the whole width. What was also needed is to set `stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally` and set the height anchor of it to the height anchor of my scroll view.

Comment: Will do some more tweaking and plan to post an answer including all the necessary cases to help my future self and perhaps others :-)

Comment: Sure, good job! It depends if you want a dynamic height based on your label content (in this case you don’t need anything else) or if you want a fixed height for your child ;)

Answer (score 0):

Had to make some tweaks to make it work.

First of all, to span over the whole width, I was missing `stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor)`, which Francesco Deliro correctly told me in the other answer.

Also, turns out I needed to change my stackViews distribution to `.fillProportionally`.

The code I was able to get what I showed on the question's picture is now this:

```
/**
 Base Class
 */
class PrototypeStackViewController: UIViewController {

    private let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let s = UIScrollView()
        s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        s.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return s
    }()

    private let stackView: UIStackView = {
        let s = UIStackView()
        s.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        s.axis = .vertical
        s.alignment = .fill
        s.distribution = .fillProportionally //CHANGED to this
        s.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        return s
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemGray

        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.addSubview(stackView)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor),
            scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor),
            scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor),

            //CHANGED set of constraints here, seems as though width and heigt anchors are needed
            stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor),
            stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.heightAnchor),
            stackView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerXAnchor),
            stackView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func add(child: UIViewController) {
        addChild(child)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(child.view)
        child.didMove(toParent: self)
    }

    func remove(child: UIViewController) {
        guard child.parent != nil else { return }

        child.willMove(toParent: nil)
        stackView.removeArrangedSubview(child.view)
        child.view.removeFromSuperview()
        child.removeFromParent()
    }
}

class PrototypeContainmentViewController: PrototypeStackViewController {

    lazy var topViewController: PrototypeSubViewController = {
        let t = PrototypeSubViewController()
        t.view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        t.label.text = "Top View Controller"
        return t
    }()

    lazy var centerViewController: PrototypeSubViewController = {
        let t = PrototypeSubViewController()
        t.view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        t.label.text = "Center View Controller"
        return t
    }()

    lazy var bottomViewController: PrototypeSubViewController = {
        let t = PrototypeSubViewController()
        t.view.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        t.label.text = "Bottom View Controller"
        return t
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()

        add(child: topViewController)
        add(child: centerViewController)
        add(child: bottomViewController)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

}

class PrototypeSubViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel()
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.textAlignment = .center
        return l
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed

        view.addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            //CHANGED to this set of constraints
            label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        ])
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Hope that this answer will help future me and potentially others as well :-)